# ant build script don't run on windows using command line

Tags: ant, build

i have written an ant script, which runs ok and generate the .jar file when i use it with eclipse. 
But when i use it on command prompt on windows xp, it's shows successfull, but nothing happens. ant is properly configured and also i can run other ant scripts.

here is my build.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="TaskNodeBundle" basedir=".">
    <!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
    <!-- The value of a property is accessed via ${} -->
    <property name="bundlename" value="task-node-bundle" />
    <property name="src.dir" location="../src" />
    <property name="lib.dir" location="../lib" />
    <property name="build.dir" location="/buildoutput" />
    <property name="build.dest" location="build/dest" />


    <!--
    Create a classpath container which can be later used in the ant task
  -->
    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}/">
            <include name="*.jar" />

        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="clean">
            <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
            <delete dir="${build.dest}" />
    </target>


    <!-- Deletes the existing build directory-->
    <target name="mkdir" depends="clean">
            <mkdir dir="${build.dest}"/>
    </target>


<!-- Compiles the java code -->
    <target name="compile" depends="mkdir">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dest}" classpathref="classpath" />
    </target>

    <target name="package-bundle" depends="compile" description="Generates the bundle">
        <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/${bundlename}.jar">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="**/**.class" />
                <include name="**/**.properties"/>
                <include name="/META-INF/**.*" />
                <include name="/META-INF/spring/**.*" />
            </fileset>

        </jar>
    </target>


</project>
```

Comment: How do you execute it? Which target do you specify on the command line? If you just call "ant" it will be the first target in the file "clean" as you don't specify a default

Comment: by typing ant and build.xml is there in the directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you execute an ant script from the command line it will execute the first target defined in the `build.xml` file (in your case `clean`).

You can specify the target(s) to be executed on the command line

```
$ ant target1 target2
```

or define a default target in your build.xml file with the default attribute of the `<project>` tag:

```
<project name="TaskNodeBundle" basedir="." default="package-bundle">
```